# How to know when a new package version using bower?

Tags: bower

I am using bower see dependencies from my bower.json below, so the question is I want bower to give a report of dependencies with newer version release but without installing it, for insatnce using npm-check-updates for npm give a nice list of dependencies that are outdated.

```
...
 "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.3.0-beta.17",
        "angular-animate": "1.3.0-beta.17",
        "angular-mocks": "1.3.0-beta.17",
        "angular-resource": "1.3.0-beta.17",
        "angular-route": "1.3.0-beta.17",
        "angular-ui-select2": "~0.0.5",
        "underscore": "~1.x",
        "bootstrap": "~3.x",
        "components-font-awesome": "~4.x",
        "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
        "ng-grid": "~2.0.11",
        "AngularJS-Toaster": "~0.4.6",
        "intro.js": "~0.9.0",
        "angular-intro.js": "~1.1.1"
    },
...
```

Answer (score 13):

You can just do `bower ls` and it'll tell you which packages are outdated. However there's discussion regarding adding an `outdated` command alias to be consistent with other package managers, included `npm`. You can voice your support here: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1138